# Accessing the view which has the dependecy

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine2.0

I have two js files, in which one view in a separate file. I am testing it using Jasmine unit testing. I have the js files included in the jasmine.html page. I am able to access everything other than the following view. The problem I am facing is when I tried to access the view from the console it says that app.TodoView is not a constructor where I am doing wrong?
Also I have a dependency in another file

```
var app = app || {};
app.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: "li",
template: _.template($("#item-template").html()),

initialize: function() {

    this.render();
},

render: function() {

    console.log("rendering");
    console.log(this.collection);
    var template = _.template($("#item-template").html())
    template = this.template({
        persons: this.collection.toJSON()
    });
    $('#todo-list').html(template);
    this.$el.html(template);

    return this;
},

});
app.TodoView = new app.TodoView()
```

Dependency(in another js file under another view) ----
    app.TodoView = new app.TodoView({
       collection : data
    });

Comment: `app.TodoView = new app.TodoView()` is overriding the constructor with an instance

Comment: *I meant _overwriting_, not overriding

Comment: Here I am creating an instance for app.TodoView so is there any other way to use app.TodoView in another View

Comment: Remove the line pointed in my previous comment, and just use `var viewInstance = new app.TodoView();` anywhere.

Comment: That didn't work I have tried that as well. Is there any other way

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "That didn't work" ? Please see [ask]

Comment: Update your question, nobody is going to read (unformatted) code in the hidden comments.